# [Android Live Wallpaper]How to start Activity when user clicked the "Set Wallpaper" button?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I just downloaded this live wallpaper:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.krisskringle.wallpaper.snowadfree

I then browse the Live Wallpaper gallery, choose the Snow Wallpaper I just downloaded from the link above, then press the "set wallpaper".

At this point, the 'disclaimer' page comes up. Do you know how the author of this app do that? How can he start an Activity when user clicked on the Set Wallpaper button?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are still looking for an answer, let me know and I'll make sure you get the complete answer.